# How to get localized CFBundleDisplayName

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

this API returns Bundle Display Name in plist.

However my app is localized and has different display name.

so i need to get localized display name in `InfoPlist.strings` that should vary with device language setting.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Have you tried `-[NSBundle localizedInfoDictionary]`?

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedInfoDictionary]
       objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

Comment: @Umgre you're welcome. there are a ton of APIs -- lots to memorize =)

Comment: This method more directly returns a localized string too:
`[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]`

Answer (score 6):

Try this for Swift:

```
// Localized
if let displayName = Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
    print("App Display Name - \(displayName)")
}

// Non-Localized
if let displayName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
    print("App Display Name - \(displayName)")
}
```

Also try this, if you have not set Display Name

```
// Localized
if let appName = Bundle.main. localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
    print("App Name - \(appName)")
}

// Non-Localized
if let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
    print("App Name - \(appName)")
}
```

Useful trick:

```
// Print bundle info dictionary to get complete details about app
print("Bundle.main.infoDictionary - \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary)")
print("Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary - \(Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary)")
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use [`kCFBundleNameKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/kcfbundlenamekey?language=objc):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String ?? ""
```

Use of this method is preferred over other access methods because it returns the localized value of a key when one is available.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
class Utils {
    static var localizedAppName: String? {
        return Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary on this? Code-only answers don't tend to age well.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in Swift 5:

```
extension Bundle {
    var displayName: String? {
        return Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
    }
}
  
if let displayName = Bundle.main.displayName {
    print("displayName : \(displayName)")
}
```